# API for youtube TV pairing in android

Tags: youtube-api

I wonder is there open android API for Youtube TV pairing.

As I know, we can control Youtube on TV or browser(www.youtube.com/tv) using Youtube on mobile or "Youtube remote" app in play store.
But to do this, we should pair Youtubes in TV(or browser) and mobile first.

I try to find some API related with paring or youtube paring application, but I can't.

Please let me know it is possible to use Youtube pairing API for android.
ex)API for generate pairing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to build general "pairing" functionality, this can be done using something called "[OAuth for Devices](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices)". You could add videos to a playlist which is being autocycled in a browser. A [demo of this functionality is here](http://stb-web-app.appspot.com/static/index.html), with source code for the [sample app in Python here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/ytplayer/stb-web-app/).